# How to set the background color of a button that has a style applied to it from code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, styles

So I have a button which has a style applied to it. The code for the button is this:

```
<Button Command="w:Command.ShowTBDisplay" Style="{DynamicResource button_displayOptions}" Content="Display TextBlock" Height="34.5" Margin="0,4,0,0" Name="btn_displayTB" />
```

When the button is clicked, I want to change its background color (permanently, until a different button is clicked). The color that I want to use is a dynamicResource..

Inside the ShowTBDisplay_Executed method, I have code like this:

```
btn_displayTB.Background = FindResource("cClickColor") as Brush;
```

But when I do this, nothing happens, no color is set.

I figure that the Style's color overwrites what ever I try to change it to...but I am not sure.

So how do I go about changing the backColor of a button with a style applied to it.

Here is the style of the button, as well as the color that I wish to use (both styles are in the app.xaml file):

```
<Style x:Key="button_displayOptions" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="{DynamicResource cMenuBackground}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="tb" TextBlock.Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,5,0,5" Height="19.5"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle" Value="{DynamicResource cMenuItemHighlight}"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" TargetName="tb" Value="Black"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="cMenuItemHighlight">#FFAFAFAF</SolidColorBrush>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your template overrides the default one and the `Background` property of the Button is no longer doing anything, you need to bind some control inside the template to the property using a `TemplateBinding` for example.

**Edit:** The rectangle should not have a concrete fill value in the template, this is probably what you want:

```
<Style x:Key="button_displayOptions" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource cMenuBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="tb" TextBlock.Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,5,0,5" Height="19.5" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True" />
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True" />
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="rectangle"
                                Value="{DynamicResource cMenuItemHighlight}" />
                        <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" TargetName="tb" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True" />
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Note the new `Setter` which sets the `Background` to your resource and the internal `TemplateBinding` on the `Rectangle.Fill`.

Comment: I'm still pretty new to wpf/xaml. Could you please elaborate a little? like where am I supposed to put in the template binding (I assume to the fill color of the style?), and what sort of value should I give it? thanks